# how ftp client knows about ftp server port no?while sending data

Tags: ftp, network-protocols

I open ftp connection,it is opening with server port 21 and client port is random(49938).
but while try to download file from ftp server,client opens one more tcp connection,like client port is 49939 and server port is 51681.
my question is How client comes to know 51681?
and usually Ftp server uses 20 port for data connection.
what is the relation?

Comment: Did you try doing some research? The FTP protocol and all related questions about opening ports have been thoroughly documented on the web and this site. See [Active FTP vs. Passive FTP, a Definitive Explanation](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html), for example.

Answer (score 0):

[Server passive port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j8RS.png)

When client request for passive mode, server reply with passive port number which will be used by client to open TCP connection for Data.Please see attached wireshark pic.